# MySQL sorting Ä and Ö with utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

Is there any way to sort characters Ä and Ö correctly without changing collation of connection? I'm using PHP and PDO.

If it's not sensible... I tried to convert every table to utf8_swedish_ci using
`ALTER TABLE tablename COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;` but it seems not working. There are still Ä before A. What's wrong?

**EDIT:** I manually set every field to `utf8_swedish_ci` and now it's working, but is there any easier way to that?

Comment: fields can have different collation from their containing table as well...

Comment: @MarcB, is there any way to make field's collation be always same than table's?

Comment: remove any overrides on the field itself, and its hould just use whatever's on the table, though you should probably force the field to be whatever the table's collation is before removing the field override - not sure if mysql will convert for you or just the original binary data in place.

Answer (score 0):

Take this table as example:

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
    `countryid` INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country` VARCHAR(44) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`countryid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

For the country column to sort correctly use this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `countries`
    CHANGE COLUMN `country` `country` VARCHAR(44) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_swedish_ci' AFTER `countryid`;
```

As you mentioned you need the collate on the column you want to sort.